# HttpConnection package

Tags: java, apache, http, connection

I want to download the httpConnection class from apache but I cant find a link, also need to know how to import it and where to put the class files when i have them.

Answer (score 5):

You mean the [`org.apache.http.HttpConnection`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.html) interface? That's part of the [HttpComponents Core library](http://hc.apache.org/). You can just download it from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). Extract the zip and just put the JAR file containing the classes in the classpath.

---

**Update**: as per your comment, I see that you're totally new to Java. I would strongly recommend to leave the `HttpConnection` bit for what it is and start to familiarize yourself with the basic Java concepts. [This is a good place to get started](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html). The classpath part is explained in [this chapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and in more technical detail in [this article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Note that there are basically two ways to define the classpath, one using the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable and other using the `-classpath` or `-cp` argument of `javac.exe` and `java.exe`. You can use only the one or the other, not both. I'd suggest to just use the `-cp` argument.

Comment: where exactly is the class path?

Comment: That's just an abstract term to indicate the location from where the JVM has to load classes from. Usually, this is to be specified using the `-classpath` or `-cp` argument of `javac.exe` and `java.exe`.

Comment: i edited the class path and put the jar in the path and yet when i try import on netbeans it doesnt work.

Comment: OK, you're new to Netbeans as well. In an IDE like Netbeans the classpath is called *Build Path*. You need to add the JAR file to the build path in the project's properties.